# Magento ACP Category Manager Broken?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm having a strange issue in the ACP where the manage categories page looks like this: http://screencast.com/t/IcNbpP87  I'd really appreciate any insight you guys may be able to provide.

I've looked around for a couple days and am pulling my hair out.

Chrome 
Displays a “New Root Category” form but you are unable to click a category to modify it.

Firefox & Safari: 
Seems to return the proper data via ajax from the server, though it displays the information without parsing(?)

Looking at the source in firebug, it looks like data that isn’t being parsed correctly within the otherwise correct `<div id="category-edit-container" class="category-content">`
Source reference: http://pastebin.com/Zz7pKajj

I’d appreciate any suggestion on how to potentially move forward and get this fixed up.  Thanks!

Comment: :Did you ever manage to get a fix for this problem. Coz I am having exactly the same problem now. Please let me know if you did find any fix? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going two day crazy with this issue in our case the solution was on the most unexpected location: **It was the index.php that was corrupted** the culprit. After removing some spurious code that seemed that was injected or by some way modified  all is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If there is content before the doctype header you will get this error. Check for that.